# docker swarm throwing an error "swarm already part of swarm"

Tags: python, docker, docker-swarm

#### docker swarm throwing an error "swarm already part of swarm" when I am joining the new node to the existing node

I am running the docker swarm in my local machine and trying to init the swarm and getting executed very well but when i am trying to add the new worker or node to the existing manager node then it is throwing an error like swarm already part of the node you have to leave the node.
$docker swarm init
Swarm initialized: current node (fn405d6jtk8mxbpvdrftr0np1) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

```
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-5tyw8ux789wpa7yyt75qbilb669tiw53pxriyxu48niznpmaka-7u63l4hom3h60myvtyw8p1mcj 192.168.2.219:2377
```

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.

=>And again am using above token as a worker and join then i gotta error like this..

```
$    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-5tyw8ux789wpa7yyt75qbilb669tiw53pxriyxu48niznpmaka-7u63l4hom3h60myvtyw8p1mcj 192.168.2.219:2377

Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
```

Comment: are you running the `docker swarm join` commands on the same node (the manager) or on different nodes?

Comment: on the same node .

Comment: but it is not possible/logic to add the same node (or vm) to the same swarm.

Comment: you need to have other nodes or virtual machines (vm) and add those.

Comment: Once we initiated swarm,then we got  two option either we can connect that node as manager or worker with the same help of join token but when i am trying any one among them then it is throwing error.For ex you can try on terminal by firing the  docker swarm init command.i have been tried lot of time i am new  to this things so i cant get the correct idea about this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) is a collection of one or more machines (physical or virtual, called nodes) that can run your containers as services. Nodes in the swarm can be managers or workers. Only on manager nodes can you see/modify the swarm status. Worker nodes only run containers. In order to run a container in the swarm you must create a service; that service will have zero or more containers depending on the `scale` that you set for the service.

To create a swarm, you run the `docker swarm init` on the machine that will be a manager node. Then, **on the other machines** that you own you run the `docker swarm join` command in order to add them to the swarm. You cannot add to the swarm a machine that already is on the swarm. In your case, you try to add to the swarm the manager that created the swarm.

When you initiate a swarm (with `docker swarm init`), the machine from that you initiated the swarm is already connected to the swarm, you don't need to do anything else to connect it to the swarm.

After you initiate the swarm, you may (and should) add other machines as managers or workers.

At any point after you have created the swarm, you can [create services](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/) and/or [networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) or [deploy stacks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using same Manager node for worker, I think it gonna make error. You can join a seperate node (can be virtual) as worker.

Type docker info and see the swarm state, you can find the state of swarm.

From the worker(different node) if you face "This node is already part of a swarm" , you should leave from swarm by " docker swarm leave --force". and try connecting again.

Comment: `docker swarm leave --force` works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The node you run `docker swarm init` on automatically becomes a Swarm Manager. Those join tokens are created for adding new nodes to the swarm to ensure you have a highly-available environment that is as resilient as possible.

Based on the comments I read above, you confirmed you were running the worker join token on the node you ran `docker swarm init`. I'd advise you read over the basics of [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) and [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/#what-is-a-swarm).

Answer (score 1):

follow the steps to add a node to a swarm
lets have 1 master1 and 3 slave nodes.

```
  $ docker-machine create -d virtualbox master1
  $ docker-machine create -d virtualbox slave1
  $ docker-machine create -d virtualbox slave2
  $ docker-machine create -d virtualbox slave3
```

now ssh to the master1

```
  $ docker ssh master1
```

now initialize the swarm cluster with master1 as a Leader

```
  $ docker swarm --init <master1-ip>  // get the ip as $ docker-machine ip master1
  $ exit
```

the above command gives token for the workers to join the swarm.
to use this token  SSH into the slave nodes. now come out of the master1 ssh

```
  $ docker-machine ssh slave1 
  $ docker swarm join-token <token> <ip>:<port>
  $ exit
```

now similarly for other slave nodes

```
  $ docker-machine ssh slave2
  $ docker swarm join-token <token> <ip>:<port>
  $ exit

  $ docker-machine ssh slave3
  $ docker swarm join-token <token> <ip>:<port>
  $ exit
```

to get a better know of the current master and slave nodes
ssh into the maste1 node

```
  $ docker-machine ssh master1
  $ docker node ls
```

**the above command is were u will come to know which nodes are already part of the swarm**

to leave the swarm

```
  $ docker swarm leave --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue,  I had one slave node which was a part of the docker swarm and then my node machine got rebooted after that I tried to add this same node again back to the swarm where it gave me below error
I had to use docker swarm leave form this node and then I again added it and it worked fine

Error:-

```
[######@slave ~]$  docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-3nvdabrgv2sg03j9u3ww5or8ujamztqv0tihzo9ip26ewtc0vq-dw5ah2sj4nwbtuvd7lmpecjzp 192.168.xxx.xxx:2377

Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
```

Resolution:-

```
[#####n@slave ~]$ docker swarm leave
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do same. Have 3 nodes. On Master node , Ran 'docker swarm init'. Now on Slave node ran command `sudo docker swarm join --token <Token-ID> <IP>:2377` But gets an error: "Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connec tcp :2377: connect: no route to host"
". Can someone assist please

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32818416)